# R descale data back to their original values

Tags: r, scaling

I have the following reproducible data:

`MyScaledData` contains scaled values between 0 and 1 for 6 variables. `minvec` and `maxvec` are named vectors and contain the maximum and minimum values from the original data set that was used to create the scaled data frame `MyScaledData`. `minvec` and `maxvec` contain values for all 22 variables of the original data set, including the 6 variables I have now in `MyScaledData`.

```
 X14863    X15066    X15067     X15068    X15069    X15070
 0.6014784 0.6975109 0.5043208 0.15284648 0.9416364 0.7860731
 0.2495215 0.7801444 0.6683925 0.13768245 0.4277954 0.2058412
 0.6167705 0.3344044 0.9254125 0.12777565 0.3826231 0.2590457
 0.1227380 0.4448501 0.3961802 0.19117246 0.7789835 0.7587897
 0.7299760 0.6375931 0.5760061 0.44746838 0.3634903 0.1079679
 0.1988647 0.7814712 0.6572054 0.71409305 0.6715690 0.4029459
 0.5041371 0.6374958 0.9333635 0.89057831 0.5716711 0.7219823
 0.5774327 0.7677038 0.7622717 0.45288270 0.2817869 0.2572325
 0.6809509 0.6089656 0.8191862 0.01151454 0.2780449 0.4655353
 0.5754383 0.5662045 0.7003630 0.62559642 0.2865510 0.1847980

MyScaledData<-structure(list(X14863=c(0.601478444979532,0.249521497274968,0.616770466379489,0.122737966507165,0.729975993009922,0.198864661389536,0.504137054265617,0.577432671357089,0.680950947164095,0.575438259547452),X15066=c(0.697510926657699,0.780144354632397,0.334404422875259,0.444850091405716,0.637593061483412,0.781471212351781,0.637495834667556,0.7677038048039,0.608965550162107,0.566204459603197),X15067=c(0.50432083998529,0.668392530333367,0.925412484830622,0.396180214305286,0.576006062451239,0.657205387087382,0.933363470346907,0.762271729415789,0.819186151914183,0.700362991098644),X15068=c(0.152846483002917,0.137682446305942,0.127775652495726,0.191172455317975,0.447468375530484,0.714093046059637,0.890578310935752,0.452882699805154,0.011514536383708,0.625596417031532),X15069=c(0.94163636689763,0.427795395079331,0.38262308941233,0.77898345642139,0.363490265569212,0.671568951210917,0.571671115989958,0.281786881885636,0.278044876559552,0.286551022600823),X15070=c(0.786073059382553,0.205841229942702,0.259045736299276,
0.758789694211416,0.107967864736275,0.402945912782515,0.721982268066207,0.257232456508833,0.46553533255268,0.184798001614338)),row.names=c(NA,10L),class="data.frame"); minvec<-c(X14861=22.95,X14862=29.95,X14863= 39.95,X15066=59.95,X15067=79.95,X15068=14.99,X15069=24.99,X15070=33.45,X15071=36.95,X15072=44.95,X15073=54.95,X15074=74.95,X15132=12.95,X15548=12.95,X15549=22.95,X15550=29.95,X15551=39.95,X15552=59.95,X15553=79.95,X15956=49.95,X15957=49.95,X16364=3.5);maxvec<-c(X14861=29.99,X14862=39.99,X14863=49.99,X15066=79.99,X15067=99.99,X15068=19.99,X15069=29.99,X15070=39.99,X15071=49.99,X15072=59.99,X15073=79.99,X15074=99.99,X15132=19.99,X15548=19.99,X15549=29.99,X15550=39.99,X15551=49.99,X15552=79.99,X15553=99.99,X15956=59.99,X15957=59.99,X16364=9.99)
```

I want to rescale back `MyScaledData` to their original scale by matching the min/max values to each corresponding column based on name. I've tried the following:

```
descale <- function(x,minval,maxval) {x*(maxval-minval) + minval}
as.data.frame(Map(descale,MyScaledData,minvec,maxvec))
```

The output I get has more than 6 columns than MyScaledData has. I sense that the function is not even matching columns by names and therefore the output is not calculated correctly. How can I match the function by column name so it takes the corresponding minvec and maxvec element for each column and return only the 6 columns I have?

Desired output shall be:

```
MyDeScaledData <- structure(list(X14863 = c(45.9888435875945, 42.4551958326407,46.1423754824501, 41.1822891837319, 47.2789589698196, 41.9466012003509,45.0115360248268, 45.7474240204252, 46.7867475095275, 45.7274001258564), X15066 = c(73.9281189702203, 75.5840928668332, 66.6514646344202,68.8647958317706, 72.7273649521276, 75.6106830955297, 72.7254165267378,75.3347842482702, 72.1536696252486, 71.2967373704481), X15067 = c(90.0565896333052,93.3445863078807, 98.4952661960057, 87.8894514946779, 91.4931614915228,93.1203959572311, 98.654603945752, 95.2259254574924, 96.3664904843602,93.9852743416168), X15068 = c(15.7542324150146, 15.6784122315297,15.6288782624786, 15.9458622765899, 17.2273418776524, 18.5604652302982,19.4428915546788, 17.2544134990258, 15.0475726819185, 18.1179820851577), X15069 = c(29.6981818344881, 27.1289769753967, 26.9031154470616,28.8849172821069, 26.8074513278461, 28.3478447560546, 27.8483555799498,26.3989344094282, 26.3802243827978, 26.4227551130041), X15070 = c(38.5909178083619,34.7962016438253, 35.1441591153973, 38.4124846001427, 34.1561098353752,36.0852662695976, 38.171764033153, 35.1323002655678, 36.4946010748945,34.6585789305578)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The data has no columns minvec and maxvec so the function cannot "match" them. Given one or two columns, what would minvec and maxvec refer to?

Comment: Correct, the minvec and maxvec are named vectors. In the scenario MyData had 2 columns then the function should match the 2 columns from minvec and maxvec.

Comment: Could you add what the expected output should look like?

Comment: Would it help if we make minvec and maxvec dataframes?

Comment: @NelsonGon added the output

Comment: Is my question clear or may I add more info? :)

Comment: What do you expect to use as minval/maxval? Is it user defined or part of the dataset. If the latter, is it per column or entire dataset? It is also a bit unclear where the maxvec comes from.

Comment: @NelsonGon the minval/maxval shall use the matching values from the minvec and maxvec. For example in the descale function the X15067 column from MyScaledData shall use 79.95 from minvec and 99.99 from maxvec.

Comment: minvec and maxvec were part of the original dataset (before scaling) and are defined per column

Comment: change as.data.frame(Map(descale,MyScaledData,minvec,maxvec)) to as.data.frame(Map(descale,MyScaledData,minvec[names(MyScaledData)],maxvec[names(MyScaledData)]))

Comment: Thank you so much @Sirin Yavari, you made my day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Shirin Yavari for providing the solution:

```
MyDeScaledData<-as.data.frame(Map(descale,MyScaledData,minvec[names(MyScaledData)],maxvec[names(MyScaledData)]))
```